# In the geometry package, what's the practical use of setting heightrounded=true?

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, geometry

In the `geometry` package, what's the practical use of setting `heightrounded=true`? The [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) says something about avoiding cases of "`underful vbox`", but I don't see why I need to worry about it. When you use the `geometry` package, do you enable `heightrounded`, and if so, what's your reason(ing) to do so?

Comment: The underfull vboxes that can result mean that the pages have different heights.

Comment: @egreg so do you generally enable it? or would you generally recommend enabling it? any reason *not to* ?

Comment: Yes, I always use it and recommend using it. If there weren't other reasons, at least for avoiding the underfull vbox messages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whether or not you use geometry package it's always a good idea to do this. You see equivalent code in `size10.clo` for the standard classes (unless compatibility with LaTeX2.09 is enabled).

For any computer system it's not usually a good idea to set it to solve a problem subject to unachievable constraints. There is usually no stretchability in the baseline spacing, so if you can not fill a page completely with lines of text, but specify (via `\flushbottom`) that TeX should aim to achieve that, then its algorithms can not hope to find a good solution. In practice it will just leave the the page a line short and complain about the underfull box, but if you do not mind the page being short you should set `\raggedbottom` anyway then there is not an issue.

Reasons not to do that: If you absolutely *need* the baseline of the top and bottom line to be a certain distance apart and you know there will always be additional white space to allow that to happen, then you should set lengths as you need and not allow the system to "fix" them, but this is a pretty rare requirement.